# JMeter help to process an array of json extracted data

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0

I have the below Json extractor running in JMeter
[Json Extractor setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IoUtE.png) [Thread structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u1ckB.png)

It goes through an array of objects and gets all the ActivityId values, the object below is an example of the data structure, values removed but one I need help with

```
{
    "Id": 
    "Date": 
    "SubmitterId": 
    "ImpersonatorId": 
    "ActivityType": 
    "ActivityInformation": {
        "SourceSystem": 
        "SourceId": 
        "SubmitterId": 
        "ImpersonatorId": 
        "ActivityType":
        "ActivityId": "8b238a9e-3a3c-4ed6-8fbf-255e99edb540",
        "SubmissionType":
    }
}
```

This gets approx 700 results when it runs.

When I try see the value of the variable made via a Groovy post processor script using
`log.info("Test output of json extracted " +  "${activityids}")`

I get the following error `2023-08-07 20:50:48,686 ERROR o.a.j.e.JSR223PostProcessor: Problem in JSR223 script, JSR223 PostProcessor
javax.script.ScriptException: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: activityids for class: Script13

What I need to do is somehow turn that into an array of id's, that I think will need to be stored as a JMeter variable then added to the body of the next POST call, and those ID's will return back more data.`

All help much appreciated

I know the values are stored as I can see them in a foreach controller and add a dummy sampler to output the value

I just can't workout how to do what I need

Answer (score 0):

1. You don't have `activityids` variable value, if you use Match Nr as `-1` in the [JSON Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) you will get the following JMeter Variables created:

   ```
   activityids_1=8b238a9e-3a3c-4ed6-8fbf-255e99edb540
   activityids_matchNr=1
   ```
2. It's not recommended to inline JMeter Functions or variables into Groovy scripts as only first occurrence will be cached and returned on subsequent iterations. Use `vars` shorthand for [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) class instance instead.

   ```
   log.info("Number of extracted IDs " +  vars.get("activityids_matchNr"))

   1.upto(vars.get('activityids_matchNr') as int, index -> {
       log.info(index + ': ' + vars.get('activityids_' + index))
   })
   ```

More information:

- [JSR223 Sampler Documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler)
- [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-java-classes)